# How is AI being used these days in designing ASIC?

Tags: hdl, asic

Is AI used in HDL synthesis or design?  For example, I would imagine that the process of place-and-route could benefit tremendously from the past decade developments in AI and Deep Learning.

How do companies like Marvel, Mellanox, Broadcom, Intel, etc. use AI for ASIC development both in their backend and frontend efforts?

Edit: related: [Chip Design with Deep Reinforcement Learning](https://ai.googleblog.com/2020/04/chip-design-with-deep-reinforcement.html).

Answer (score 2):

EDA tools have used what now called AI and Deep Learning for decades. It's just now that processing power and common APIs has now crossed the divide where AI can be used readily with so many different applications.

The process of placement and routing a PC board or ASIC device is very similar to how deep learning algorithms work—finding the best layouts to minimize cost functions like delay, power, and space.

Comment: I think it's very misleading to call this AI - buzzword creep has led to any kind of statistics or algorithmic refinement being called "AI".

Comment: No, this sort of CAD tool does not represent AI or any kind of learning. The algorithms used are the same every time the tool is run...it is not learning from its experience.

Comment: Right... I don't think it is doing any learning, just applying some heuristic algorithms. Surely you can call this thing AI, because it is artificial, and it has certain intelligence to do it's job. But this is not the same AI people expect to find behind these letters

Comment: I agree that layout and routing do not involve ANN, deep learning, etc. but they do fall under Good Old fashion AI.